# Cambiar color de fondo a un input cuando se selecciona una sugerencia

Tags: html, css

tengo la siguiente duda, tengo un formulario de login con los input con un fondo transparente, los cuales se ven asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al tener las contraseñas guardas me aparecen las sugerencias del usuario a seleccionar como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si selecciono una opcion el input queda con ese color que se ve en la imagen y me gustaria cambiarlo y que quede transparente como es originalmente el input con los estilos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los estilos de los inputs

```
.form-control-log{  background-color: transparent; border: none; border-radius: 0; color: #AEAEAE !important; border-bottom: 3px solid #1C1E26 !important; height: 40px; padding-right: 30px }
.form-control-log:focus{ background-color: transparent; border-bottom: 3px solid #2970CA !important }
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: correigo estimado

Answer (score 0):

Seria mas efectivo detectar el evento change del input y cuando este tenga un cambio podemos capturar el valor y almacenarlo en una variable luego establece un timeout que se ejecute en 10 mili segundos y dentro establece el valor del input a vacío (null o "") y finamente le aplicamos el valor almacenado en la variable.

de esta manera el valor del input estaría siendo aplicado por el script y no por la sugerencia.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('change',e=>{
        if(e.target.matches('input')){
            let data = new String(e.target.value)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                e.target.value = ''
                e.target.value = data
            },10)
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Una opción seria sacar el autocompletado por defecto de los inputs con el atributo `autocomplete= "off"`. De esa forma no se autocompleta y no se te pone el fondo del input con ese color.